# Getting error 500 in modal window

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, modal-dialog

I have a modal window which gives me a `Server Error in '\' Application` when I click it.

The `.aspx` looks like this:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint,     Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ChangeEmail.aspx.cs" Inherits="GOToolkitFeatures.Layouts.ToolkitTilskud.Notification.ChangeEmail" DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="PageHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
PageHead
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
Main
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="PageTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
Application Page
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="PageTitleInTitleArea" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server" >
My Application Page
</asp:Content>
```

And this is the `.js` where it's called from:

```
function ChangeEmailAction(pageUrl) {

var options = {
    title: "Skift email",
    url: pageUrl + "/_layouts/15/toolkittilskud/Notification/ChangeEmail.aspx",
    height: 600,
    width: 800,
};

SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
}
```

If I put a `console.log` in there, I can see that the function is hit, but something goes wrong.
What am I doing wrong here? Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is most likely with the URL you are using for the Dialog. The variable you are passing is named `pageUrl` if this really is the page url like:

```
http://somedomain.local/sites/yoursite/pages/yourpage.aspx
```

then the new url is just going to be that plus the `/_layouts/` portion. So something like:

```
http://somedomain.localsites/yoursite/pages/yourpage.aspx/_layouts/15/toolkittilskud/Notification/ChangeEmail.aspx
```

This will definitely throw a 500 error as that is not correct. You are wanting your siteUrl rather than the pageUrl. You can verify if this is the issue by using `console.log(options.url);` before the `SOD` call.